# SQL query with JOIN and WHERE IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

**UPDATE: Initially, I had the order date at line item table and realized that was a mistake and moved it to the Order table. Have updated my example query as well. Sorry**

I am trying to write a query to load all orders whose line item order date is after a certain date along with loading all other orders which are out there for the same product returned by the first part of the query. Maybe an example could help

```
CREATE TABLE DemandOrder 
(OrderId INT, OrderDate date, Customer VARCHAR(25))
CREATE TABLE LineItem 
(OrderId INT, LineItemId INT, ProductId VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO DemandOrder VALUES(1, '01/23/2014', 'ABC');
INSERT INTO DemandOrder VALUES(2, '01/24/2014', 'DEF');
INSERT INTO DemandOrder VALUES(3, '01/24/2014', 'XYZ');
INSERT INTO DemandOrder VALUES(4, '01/23/2014', 'ABC');

INSERT INTO LineItem VALUES(1, 1, 'A');
INSERT INTO LineItem VALUES(1, 2, 'C');
INSERT INTO LineItem VALUES(2, 1, 'B');
INSERT INTO LineItem VALUES(3, 1, 'A');
INSERT INTO LineItem VALUES(4, 1, 'C');
```

In the above example, I need to query for all orders where the order date is on or after 01/24 along with all other orders which may have the returned by the first part of the query. The result should have orders 1, 2 & 3

Here is the updated sql code (using ErikE's suggestions from a post below)

```
SELECT
 DISTINCT O.*
 FROM
 dbo.[DemandOrder] O
 INNER JOIN dbo.LineItem LI
  ON O.OrderID = LI.OrderID
 WHERE
 EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM
     dbo.DemandOrder O2 INNER JOIN
     dbo.LineItem L2 ON O2.OrderId = L2.OrderId
  WHERE
     O2.OrderDate >= '01/24/2014'
     AND LI.ProductID = L2.ProductID -- not clear if correct
);
```

Thanks for your help and suggestions

Comment: It's not clear how the first and second parts link together. You said "along with all other orders", but you didn't say "all other orders that _____ (what condition)?" It seems like you want to match either on `OrderID`, or on `ProductID`. Your example query matches on `OrderID`, but your example expected result of `(1, 2, 3)` would only work if you're matching only on `ProductID`. Which is it? Or, do you want all orders that have at least one productID that matches any product ID in an order 1/24/2014 or later?

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity, is it correct that `OrderDate` is in the `LineItem` table? Or can orders have additional line items added to them after the fact (they function more like purchase orders than product orders)?

Comment: Your example line item table has an order id not in the `order` table.  Is that correct?

Comment: @ErikE In my query, I am selecting all ProductIDs which belongs to an order after 01/24 in the subquery and using this list, I am querying all order whose line item includes the productID.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are right, I missed an order in my example. will update it

Comment: @ErikE After reading your comment, I realized the order date should be at order level and not line item level. Have made the change and updated my sample query. Sorry for the inconvenience. Yes, I need all orders that have at least one ProductID that matches any product ID in an order with order date 01/24 or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is going to be close to what you're looking for.

All orders that have at least one productID that matches any product ID in an order 1/24/2014 or later.

```
SELECT
   O.*
FROM
   dbo.[Order] O
   INNER JOIN dbo.LineItem LI
      ON O.OrderID = LI.OrderID
WHERE
   EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM
         dbo.LineItem L2
         INNER JOIN dbo.LineItem L3
            ON L2.ProductID = L3.ProductID
         INNER JOIN dbo.[Order] O2
            ON L3.OrderID = O2.OrderID
      WHERE
         O2.OrderDate >= '20140124'
         AND O.OrderID = L2.OrderID
   )
;
```

Comment: Erik, I have updated the post sample code using your sample and the query seems to return what I was expecting. If I need to do the same for querying line items as well, just by simply changing O.* to LI.* doesn't give me the desired results as it is missing LineItem 2 from Order 1. Hope, I didn't confuse you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with window functions:

```
select o.*
from (Select o.*,
             max(li.OrderDate) over (partition by li.product) as maxProductOrderDate
      from Order o INNER JOIN
           LineItem li
           ON o.OrderId = li.OrderId
     ) o
where o.maxProductOrderDate >= '2014-01-24';
```

You might actually want `select distinct` in the outer query, to prevent duplicates if one order has multiple products shipped after the given date.

As for your query, you can simplify it because you do not need the `order` table in the subquery, unless you need it for filtering purposes:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM Order o INNER JOIN
     LineItem li
     ON o.OrderId = li.OrderId
WHERE li.Product IN (SELECT li.Product
                     FROM LineItem li
                     WHERE li.OrderDate >= '2014-01-24'
                    );
```

You probably want `select distinct o.*` in the outer query, to avoid duplicates when an order has two or more products that match the condition.

Comment: Even `'yyyy-mm-dd'` is not culture-safe, only `'yyyymmdd'` or `'yyyy-mm-ddThh:nn:ss'`, try `set language french; select convert(datetime, '2014-01-24')`.

Comment: @ErikE . . . I'm aware that there are a few situation where it doesn't work.  I prefer having the hyphen for human readability; it is a compromise.  And, the hyphen are acceptable in the ISO standard date format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: I think it would be helpful for beginners, when they receive strongly prescriptive advice such as "you should use X format" that is in reality a personal preference/compromise, to also be told that information (which would simultaneously avoid--perhaps--other folks like me from commenting about less than 100% agreement on said strongly prescriptive advice).

Comment: If there are a million orders in the system, and 100 orders with any line items since '2014-01-24T00:00:00', how well will this query perform?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with window functions:

```
select o.*
from (Select o.*,
             max(li.OrderDate) over (partition by li.product) as maxOrderDate
      from Order o INNER JOIN
           LineItem li
           ON o.OrderId = li.OrderId
     ) o
where o.maxOrderDate >= '2014-01-24';
```

You might actually want `select distinct` in the outer query, to prevent duplicates if one order has multiple products shipped after the given date.

As for your query, you can simplify it.  The `order` table is not needed:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM Order o INNER JOIN
     LineItem li
     ON o.OrderId = li.OrderId
WHERE li.Product IN (SELECT li.Product
                     FROM LineItem li and li.OrderDate >= '2014-01-24'
                    );
```

Comment: If there are a million orders in the system, and 100 orders with any line items since '2014-01-24T00:00:00', how well will the first query perform?

Comment: I had made a mistake in my original post, the order date should be at order table. That was the reason I had used order in my sub query. sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

To get a result set with 1 row per order (meaning you're not interesting in line item data, just the order summary), something like this should do:

```
select o.*
from ( select distinct OrderId
       from dbo.LineItem t1
       where exists ( select *
                      from dbo.LineItem t2
                      where t2.Product = t1.Product
                        and t2.OrderDate >= @SomeLowerBoundDateTimeValue
                    )
     ) t
join dbo.Order o on o.OrderId  = t.OrderId
```

The first item in the `from` clause is a *derived table* consisting of the set of order ids associated with a product that was part of an order dated on or after the specified date. Having done that, the rest is trival: just join against the order table.

Generally, for performance, you want to use correlated subqueries with `[not] exists (...)` in preference to uncorrelated subqueries with `[not] in (...)`.

`exists` short circuits as soon as possible; `in` does not as it must construct the entire result set of the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

first i guess that your result should be OrderId: 2 and 3 because OrderDate is 01/24...

If you want to get that result you could try to do this.

```
    Select o1.OrderId,o1.CustomerName,l1.OrderDate,l1.ProductId
    from Order o1 INNER JOIN
         LineItem l1
         ON o1.OrderId = l1.OrderId
    where l1.OrderDate >= '01/242014'
```

Hope this works and solve your question.

Regards!!!

Comment: Your query will just return me orders with order date after 01/24 but I am looking for orders whose line item includes product that is returned by your query as well.

Comment: @user320587 . . . If the order date is in a different table, I would suggest that you ask another question.  This one already has six answers based on the wrong data layout.  It is unfair to those who answered to change the question so the answers look silly.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will create a new question

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for, I believe.

**Here's what's happening:**

- `JOIN LineItem liBase`: grab the initial records from LineItem based on the MinDate specification
- `JOIN LineItem liMatches`: Self JOIN to to the LineItem table using the ProductIDs collected in the initial JOIN
- `JOIN LineItem projection`: Using the OrderIDs collected from  in the previous JOIN, grab the records from the LineItem table (in an additional self JOIN)
- `SELECT projection.*`: projection is the set of results that we are after. SELECT them

**Here's the query:**

```
;WITH parms (
    MinDate
) AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/24/2014')
)

SELECT projection.* 
FROM parms p 
JOIN LineItem liBase
    ON liBase.OrderDate >= p.MinDate
JOIN LineItem liMatches 
    ON liMatches.ProductId = liBase.ProductId
JOIN LineItem projection
    ON projection.OrderId = liMatches.OrderId
ORDER BY projection.OrderId
;
```

**Same query, but with data generation (generates the LineItem and Order data sets that you presented in your question).**

```
;WITH parms (
    MinDate
) AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/24/2014')
)

, LineItem ( 
      OrderId
    , LineItemID
    , OrderDate
    , ProductId 
) AS (
    SELECT 1, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/23/2014'), 'B' UNION 
    SELECT 4, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/23/2014'), 'C' UNION 
    SELECT 2, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/24/2014'), 'A' UNION 
    SELECT 3, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/24/2014'), 'B'
) 

, [Order] (
      OrderId
    , CustomerName
) AS (
    SELECT 1, 'ABC' UNION
    SELECT 2, 'XYZ' UNION
    SELECT 3, 'DEF'
)

SELECT projection.* 
FROM parms p 
JOIN LineItem liBase
    ON liBase.OrderDate >= p.MinDate
JOIN LineItem liMatches 
    ON liMatches.ProductId = liBase.ProductId
JOIN LineItem projection
    ON projection.OrderId = liMatches.OrderId
ORDER BY projection.OrderId
;
```

Comment: Doing date math on the `LineItem` side of the join is a red flag that your answer needs improvement. Search for "sargable" online to understand why.

Comment: Hey, @ErikE. I actually removed the date math. Upon re-reading the query it became apparent to me that zeroing out the OrderDate in this case was necessary. I understand the concept of sargablity. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: It's never necessary to zero out the `OrderDate` on the **table** side of a join such as that. You would zero out the date from the **parameter** side, and then simply do a `>=`.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Reduce the values operated on to one rather than the whole column. It was one of those things I did without thinking it through before copying and pasting it. In fact, if you look through the edit history of this answer, you'll see that I had an absurd JOIN architecture in place that was TOTALLY necessary.